Deny delete option for others than submitor
How to deny possibility of deleting others comments at retrospective board - DevOps space. Currently there is possibility to delete comments that were posted by other members with access of a certain retrospective board.
At following stages - collect, group, vote a feedbacks submitted by a person can be deleted by another person with access to the boards.

I am afraid this is still an open issue as we can find in Issues · microsoft/vsts-extension-retrospectives (github.com).
In addition, since Retrospectives is a marketplace extension task, we can only report the issue and seek assistance in the publisher GitHub repo.


Microsoft DevLabs is an outlet for experiments from Microsoft. Experiments that represent some of the latest ideas around developer tools. Solutions in this category are designed for broad usage and you are encouraged to use and provide feedback on them. However, these extensions are not supported and no commitments are made as to their longevity. Please do not contact Microsoft Customer Support. For questions, suggestions, or issues with any of these extensions visit the "Q&A" section for the specific extension.

